# why do i have multi containers in a component in redux? whats the benefit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i'm beginner in **Redux** and come from **Reflux**

in the documentation [this link](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html) of **Redux** they tell "one container component at the top in **Redux** examples was a mistake. Don't take this as a maxim" why?

for example in "todo-example"  [redux example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) they have multi **Container** for Todo component and i can't understand the reason of that. i mean we can just have one **Container** and one **Presentational** component for Todo Component.

what is the benefit for have multiple container in component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/), which covers several concepts related to connecting multiple components.

As a quick summary:  connecting more components means that each component is interested in smaller parts of the Redux store state, and will need to re-render less often, so it's generally better for performance.  It also means that each component has fewer responsibilities, and should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple containers allow you to keep simple testing and development because you create a separate module/container for each components instead of having a unique container which handle all your components.

For a very small application a unique container approach could possibly even work, but in a real world application would be difficult to scale up.

Interesting article describing use of containers:

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0